# Proving a division propositon?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A,B,C are integers.

Proposition:

**If a divides $b-1$ and a divides $c-1$ then a divides $bc-1$**

Explanation

$b-1= a(k)$ k is integer

$c-1=a(t)$ t is an integer

I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have $b-1=ak$ and $c-1=at$ with $k$ and $t$ integers, now you just need to express $bc-1$ in terms of $a$.

$bc-1$ = $(ak+1)(at+1)-1$ using your definitions.
Then $bc-1$ = $a^2kt+at+ak+1-1$ = $a(akt+t+k)$

Therefore $a$ divides $bc-1$.

Comment: Thanks now I see the correct method of proving!

Answer (score 1):

$a|b-1,a|c-1\implies a|c(b-1)\implies a|c(b-1)+(c-1)=cb-c+c-1=bc-1$